# Why parse date not return as a string?

Tags: parse-platform

I query date from parse and see that my date type column return as json object

```
newsPublishDate: {
__type: "Date"
iso: "2015-10-20T11:41:00.000Z"
}
```

while createdAt column also a date type but return a String

```
createdAt: "2015-10-24T11:38:14.766Z"
```

how can i make parse return my date column as a string?
thank you so much.

Comment: Huh, interesting never noticed this before... I guess you could convert it back into a date, but that doesn't really answer your question

Comment: i have changed date type to string type in parse. so the json return will be simpler.

Answer (score 1):

@MichaelP try newsPublishDate.iso assuming the name of the variable that contains the JSON object is called newsPublishDate.